# What is fired first : submit or ng-click?

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, submit, angularjs-ng-click

First of all, excuse me if my English is bad, that's not mother tongue.

So, I have a set up a search form that returns maximum 20 items, and if there is more than that, then the user can switch between the pages. So there would be an unknown number of pages. Here's how I do right now : (example with two pages)

```
    <form class="searchForm" method="POST" action="~/Search/Products">
                            <input type="hidden" name="keyword" value="@Model.Keyword" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="pagenum" value="{{choosedPage}}" id="page" />

                            <button type="submit" ng-click="choosedPage=1" class="btn btn-primary">1</button>
                            <button type="submit" ng-click="choosedPage=2" class="btn btn-primary">2</button>
                    </form>
```

So, when the user clicks on the button, it changes "choosedPage" and directly fires the submit action with the page that we want. I Check that, **all works fine**.

**But** it seems pretty hacky though, what if the submit action is fired before the ng-click action ? Is it even possible ? Have you another idea that that (and other than creating 1 form per page button).
Thank you.

Comment: why not make them buttons instead of type="Submit" and submit the form in your javascript code after validation?

Comment: I am using Microsoft Asp.net MVC, which allows me to send the model to the controller, and then send back a view. If I do that via the javascript, the post request will return me the raw html result into the response, but not redirect me to the page with this HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first of all, you don't really need Angular to do what you are doing. You can just assign `name` and `value` to the buttons with `type="submit"`.

```
<form class="searchForm" method="POST" action="~/Search/Products">
   <input type="hidden" name="keyword" value="@Model.Keyword" />

   <button type="submit" name="pagenum" value="1" class="btn btn-primary">1</button>
   <button type="submit" name="pagenum" value="2" class="btn btn-primary">2</button>
</form>
```

The Web actually existed before Angular, you know :)

But, if you need to perform some additional Angular tasks, you can use `ng-submit` on the form element ***instead of*** `ng-click` on the button:

```
<form ng-submit="doSomethingBeforeSubmit($event)" 
      method="POST" action="~/Search/Products">
   ...
</form>
```

This will invoke `$scope.doSomethingBeforeSubmit` before the form is submitted. `$event` is a special variable that you can pass to your `doSomethingBeforeSubmit` function.

Here's the [`ng-submit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) documentation.

Comment: Alright, I thought that putting several times the same "name="pagenum"" would do weird stuff, but it seem to work. So, how does it work ? The value of pagenum is the one on the button we click on ?